# Repeating a Background Image in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Im using swift programming language in xcode and in spritekit. I want to get my background image to scroll forever. I have this code so far but when I run it in the simulator it goes through only one time and goes back to the grey background. How do I get it so that the background repeats forever. I already got the background to move its just that I want it to repeat forever.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var background = SKSpriteNode()


         // Background

    background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    addChild(background)

    // Repeat Background Image Forever

    moveForeverAction()

    }

        //loop background image infinitely

    func moveForeverAction() {
    let moveNode = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: background.size.height * 2.0 , duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * background.size.height * 2.0))
    let resetPosition = SKAction.moveByX(0, y:  background.size.height * 2.0, duration: 0)
    let moveNodeForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveNode, resetPosition]))
    background.runAction(moveNodeForever)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're adding the same background.
add another declaration of bacground in the loop :

```
for var i:CGFloat=0; i < 3; ++i {

**background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")**

background.position = CGPointMake(background.size.width / 2, i * background.size.height )
background.runAction(moveNodeForever)

}
```

Comment: It works but its not repeating like I want it to. When I first run it in the simulator my background image goes from top to bottom one time and then goes back to the grey background. Then it returns to my background image after a second and loops every 3 seconds. It doesnt give the impression that the background is moving forever. How would I get it to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You've to runAction() 3 times. For example :

for var i:CGFloat=0; i < 3; ++i {

```
background.position = CGPointMake(background.size.width / 2, i * background.size.height )
background.runAction(moveNodeForever)
```

}

Comment: I put this code in my project and got an error.                      It says                                                          Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'background' (2480 x 3507)] position:{1240, 3507} size:{2480, 3507} rotation:0.00'

Comment: I put the code in the didMoveToView is that correct because it is not working?